# Getting vcpkg Cmake/Clion errors with SFML and TGUI

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, sfml, clion, vcpkg

I am currently using Vcpkg on a windows computer on CLION IDE. I am trying to install SFML and TGui, but getting build errors.

Here is the error

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.2\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug "-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:/Program Files/JetBrains/CLion 2023.3.2/bin/ninja/win/x64/ninja.exe" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\Users\flame\.vcpkg-clion\vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\vcpkg.cmake -G Ninja -S C:\Users\flame\Documents\projects\application-projects\GuiTesting -B C:\Users\flame\Documents\projects\application-projects\GuiTesting\cmake-build-debug
CMake Error at C:/Users/flame/.vcpkg-clion/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:859 (_find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "SFML" with any of
  the following names:

    SFMLConfig.cmake
    sfml-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "SFML" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "SFML_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "SFML"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

[Failed to reload]
```

Here is the CMakesList.txt (please excuse my messy executable list)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)
project(GuiTesting)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

find_package(SFML COMPONENTS system window graphics CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(TGUI CONFIG REQUIRED)

include_directories(./include)

add_executable(GuiTesting
        src/main.cpp
        src/ui/GuiManager.cpp
        include/ui/GuiManager.h
        include/Context.h
        include/AssetManager.h
        include/StateManager.h
        src/Game.cpp
        src/AssetManager.cpp
        src/GameState.cpp
        src/GraphicsSettings.cpp
        src/StateManager.cpp
        include/GameState.h
        include/State.h
        include/MainMenu.h
        src/MainMenu.cpp
        include/ui/GuiBase.h
        src/ui/TestGuiBase.cpp
        include/ui/TestGuiBase.h
        include/ui/CardButton.cpp
        include/ui/CardButton.h
)


target_link_libraries(GuiTesting PRIVATE sfml-system sfml-network sfml-graphics sfml-window)
target_link_libraries(GuiTesting PRIVATE TGUI::TGUI)
```

and here is my debug profile's CMake options

```
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\Users\flame\.vcpkg-clion\vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\vcpkg.cmake
```

I have reinstalled vcpkg, but have been having trouble with vcpkg for some time. It is strange because it should be automatically integrated, no?

I was previously building from precompiled libraries using the following code

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)
project(GuiTesting)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)


set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
option(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS "Build shared libraries" OFF)

include_directories(./include)

set(SFML_STATIC_LIBRARIES TRUE)
set(SFML_DIR "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/SFML-2.6.1/lib/cmake/SFML/SFMLConfig.cmake")
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/SFML-2.6.1")
find_package(SFML COMPONENTS system window graphics audio network REQUIRED)


# Fetch TGUI
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/TGUI-1.1")



# Find TGUI
find_package(TGUI 1 REQUIRED)
set(TGUI_BACKEND SFML_GRAPHICS)

add_executable(GuiTesting
        src/main.cpp
        src/ui/GuiManager.cpp
        include/ui/GuiManager.h
        include/Context.h
        include/AssetManager.h
        include/StateManager.h
        src/Game.cpp
        src/AssetManager.cpp
        src/GameState.cpp
        src/GraphicsSettings.cpp
        src/StateManager.cpp
        include/GameState.h
        include/State.h
        include/MainMenu.h
        src/MainMenu.cpp
        include/ui/GuiBase.h
        src/ui/TestGuiBase.cpp
        include/ui/TestGuiBase.h
        include/ui/CardButton.cpp
        include/ui/CardButton.h

)
target_link_libraries(GuiTesting PRIVATE sfml-graphics)
target_link_libraries(GuiTesting PRIVATE TGUI::TGUI)
target_compile_features(GuiTesting PRIVATE cxx_std_17)



install(TARGETS GuiTesting)
```

but each time I attempted to run code I ran into hellishly long build/execution times. I don't at all understand CMake despite my best efforts, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you actually install SFML using vcpkg?

Comment: Are you using the same compiler with vcpkg as you are in CLion and VSCode? I ask this because if you are using a msvc triplet and generate msvc binaries for your c++ based libraries you can't expect to use those binaries with MinGW.

Comment: ***I don't at all understand CMake despite my best efforts*** My advice is to take vcpkg and your end goal of this application using SFML and TGUI out of the picture for a few hours. Instead try some practice CMake example projects. Make your own c++ based library. Use that library in a separate CMakeLists.txt in a completely different folder where you write a small application to test that library. This way you you can understand what is happening before you move into more complicated CMake involving vcpkg

Comment: Yes. I installed SFML and vcpkg